# Event for bulk updating product status : M2

Tags: magento2, massaction

I am trying to find event when admin mass update product status from productgrid.

This event `catalog_controller_product_mass_status`is not available in magento2, so can any one help me which event i can use.

I want to execute my custom function which check product status when we update product status using mass action.

Answer (score 0):

In that class "Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassStatus" magento maintains update mass status action.

So you can use before/after/around magento2 plugin.